# GUnload is null or undefined using Directions Service

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I'm getting an error using Google Maps API V3 that I don't understand.  My initial map displays just fine, but when I try to get directions, I get the following two errors:

Error: The value of the property 'GUnload' is null or undefined, not a Function object

Error: Unable to get value of the property 'setDirections': object is null or undefined

I'm not using GUnload anywhere, so I don't understand why I'm getting that error.  As far as the second error is concerned, it's as if something is wrong with the Directions service.

Here is my code:

```
var directionsDisplay;
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
var map;
function initialize(address) {

  directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
  var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(42.733963, -84.565501);
  var mapOptions = {
   center: latlng,
   zoom: 15,
   mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
 };
 map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
 geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status) {
   if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
     map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
     var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
       map: map,
       position: results[0].geometry.location
     });
   } else {
     alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason:  " + status);
   }
 });
 directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
}

function getDirections(start, end) {
 var request = {
  origin:start,
  destination:end,
  travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
 };
 directionsService.route(request, function(result, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
    directionsDisplay.setDirections(result);
  } else {
    alert("Directions cannot be displayed for the following reason:  " + status);
  }
 });
}
```

I'm not very savvy with javascript, so I could have made some sort of error there.  I appreciate any help I can get.

Comment: Please show us how you load the API.

Comment: I actually do that in the .NET code:

Comment: Dim url As New StringBuilder ("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=")
    url.Append(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings(BusinessLogicLayer.Common.GoogleMapsApiKey))
    url.Append("&sensor=false")
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptInclude _
        (BusinessLogicLayer.Common.GoogleMapsInclude, url.ToString)

Comment: It ends up being:
  <script type="text/javascript"      
  src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAo4esdKzJ-RXdJTYB4EKPBzkByO0FJhFo&sensor=false">    </script>

Comment: Never mind .NET. What matters is what gets to the browser. Look only at the javascript.

Comment: When I view source, I see:
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAo4esdKzJ-RXdJTYB4EKPBzkByO0FJhFo&amp;sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: Try clicking the link you just posted ;-)

Comment: I don't understand.  It works for the initial map.  What is wrong with it?

Comment: It is the '&amp;' before the sensor parameter. The server cannot read the sensor parameter. Use a simple '&' instead.

Comment: In addition to the previous message, after sensor=false there is a quotation mark, which should not be there. The script URL should be: http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAo4esdKzJ-RXdJTYB4EKPBzkByO0FJhFo&sensor=false

Comment: I put the proper link directly in the page (instead of adding it dynamically through .NET), and I'm still getting the same results:  the initial map loads, but I get the same two errors when I try to get the directions.  Viewing the source gives me the proper string.

Comment: Then post a link to your page. This is becoming a waste of time.

Comment: Sorry.  I can't post a link to my page, since it's just on my local machine so far.  Thanks for the help you've given me so far.  I won't waste any more of your time.

Answer (score 0):

GUnload is a Google Maps API v2 thing. If you are getting an error that says it is undefined, that means that some of your code (or the code you have included in your application) is using it, and you are using the Google Maps API v3, which doesn't provide it.

Can't comment on the setDirections issue without seeing more context, but most likely is due to trying to call it before the API code is loaded.